# Limit the number of items in menu in react quizzes

Tags: reactjs

I am using react quizzes library:
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-quizzesexample-forked-2w1gj?file=/src/index.js:408-499 
According to the [documentation](https://github.com/hugobarragon/react-quizzes) we can choose just these kind of builder items from menu that we want using `toolBox`.

I want to leave just Checkboxes in the menu but i didn't find a solution for this. Who can help?

```js
function App() {
  const [formdata, setFormData] = useState([]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <QuizzBuilder onChange={setFormData} />
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This package `react-quizzes`, looks not really great. Its final build not include all modules, and require importing things directly. But if you want, here's the solution:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { QuizzBuilder } from "react-quizzes";
import ToolBox from "react-quizzes/lib/ToolBox";
import "react-quizzes/lib/assets/antd.css";

const filteredToolBox = ToolBox().filter(el => el.field_name === "checkboxes_")

function App() {
  const [formdata, setFormData] = useState([]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <QuizzBuilder toolBox={filteredToolBox} onChange={setFormData} />
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

### Update #1

Added logic to override `ToolBox` label

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { QuizzBuilder } from "react-quizzes";
import QuizExample from "./QuizExample";
import "react-quizzes/lib/assets/antd.css";
import ToolBox from "react-quizzes/lib/ToolBox";
import { defaultMessages } from "react-quizzes/lib/translations/TranslatedText";

const filteredToolBox = ToolBox().filter(
  (el) => el.field_name === "checkboxes_"
);

const messages = {
  en: {
    ...defaultMessages.en,
    "toolbox.checkboxes.name": "Here are Checkboxes"
  }
};

function App() {
  const [formdata, setFormData] = useState([]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <QuizzBuilder
        messages={messages}
        toolBox={filteredToolBox}
        onChange={setFormData}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: could you help me to set just one language for this builder, i try language="en"` but i does not help, anyway PT language still when i open editor.

Comment: from [source code](https://github.com/hugobarragon/react-quizzes/blob/master/src/ToolBox/index.tsx#L25-L39) you can see that's hardcoded and not configurable

Comment: you can override `options` and `questions` with your custom values, but it's antipattern... generally, this package is also antipattern, so feel free what you like)

Comment: thanks, one more question related to this. Maybe you know a trick.  If you will open my sandbox, you will see that in the left side is a menu with different types of block. Is there a solution to change the title on the item? ex: `Radio Buttons`  to `Here are radio buttons`. Thanks in advance.

Comment: adding this `console.log(filteredToolBox.filter(i => i.key ? i.name = 'Test' : i.key));` it works but i get an error :id not found in current language messages . Could you help?

Comment: `you can override options and questions with your custom values`. So is there a possibility to remove one language?

Comment: Yes, but I don't want to do that, because as I said it's antipattern. You can do it by your own in any way you like

Comment: but how to do this?

Comment: maybe you know, but how to select the right answer? Because hen i create one and select an answer as correct and save the doc, i don't get any etails that i selected one or another data. Could help? Thanks

Comment: Sorry, you extending this topic, please create another question SO.

Comment: could you help with this please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66303961/use-spread-operator-to-combine-multiple-arrays-fetching-data-in-react-js